Prevent optimization of arithmetic computation
I need to implement this paper
Page 5, there is a function
void Split(double a, double *x, double *y) {
   double z = a * ((1 << r) + 1);
   *x = z - (z - a);
   *y = a - *x;
}

With -O3 (which I need for the rest of the program, gcc sees that z - (z - a) can be simplified to a (but only when function is inlined) :
Split(double, double*, double*):
  movsd .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
  mulsd %xmm0, %xmm1
  movapd %xmm1, %xmm2
  subsd %xmm0, %xmm2
  subsd %xmm2, %xmm1
  subsd %xmm1, %xmm0
  movsd %xmm1, (%rdi)
  movsd %xmm0, (%rsi)
  ret
.LC3:
  .string "%lf -- %lf\n"
main:
  subq $8, %rsp
  movl $.LC3, %edi
  movl $2, %eax
  movsd .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
  movsd .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
  call printf
  xorl %eax, %eax
  addq $8, %rsp
  ret
.LC0:
  .long 67108864
  .long 1099956224
.LC1:
  .long 0
  .long -1104234414
.LC2:
  .long -335544320
  .long 1073920081

assembly for the function itself is not optimized but in the caller (main), all intermediate operations vanish.
How can I have this function inlined but no optimization for it
Do I really have to write inline assembly ? Or is there any compiler hint ?
[EDIT] : i can add a volatile to z and prevent optimization. But then, compiler is not able to vectorize properly

Do you have -ffast-math or -Ofast in your compiler flags?  This shouldn't usually happen.

@fuz nope, I just compile with O3

Constant-propagation through FP operations is still allowed if main is calling it with compile-time constant arguments.  You can use __attribute__((noipa)) to block all inter-procedural analysis (including inlining) in GCC, or __attribute((noinline)) in clang or GCC to just block inlining.

Strategic use of volatile or asm("" : "+x"(fp_var)) can get the compiler to forget what it knows about a variable after materializing it in memory or in a register, but with volatile copy it to a non-volatile variable if you don't want the asm to be stupid.  Using inline asm the way Benchmark::DoNotOptimize does can force a certain value to exist in a register.  "+x" requires that to be the bottom of an XMM register, so will still defeat auto-vectorization.

@PeterCordes Indeed i call with constant argument. When function is called on memory, everything is vectorized as expected. Great !

Highly related: How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output? talks about how to write functions that compile to interesting asm: take args and return a value (or do side-effects on pointed-to memory).  So like you found, write a function that takes pointers and loops over arrays to see this auto-vectorizing on https://godbolt.org/.  If you're going to look at the asm, you don't need a runnable main.

The transformation you see is controlled by this.

What is the source here?  The values used in main might matter.

Wait a minute, are the values printed by main actually different from what you get with volatile or optimization disabled?  i.e. was constant-propagation was done with higher temporary precision than it should have been with FLT_EVAL_METHOD==0 like GCC has for x86-64?  Or are you just noticing that there's no FP math at all in main's asm, just printing constants?  Have you tried with g++ -std=c++23 instead of gnu++23, to imply -fexcess-precision=standard?  Related: Comparing double with literal value in C gives different results on 32 bit machines

See also Different behaviour of double to integer in different architectures and unit tests
and C++ handling of excess precision (@PasserBy -  -fassociative-math is off by default, but -fexcess-precision=fast is on by default, for the default -std=gnu++23 or whatever version, unlike for -std=c++23.)
